# Can tangoApplication.m_3drResolutionMeters be updated during runtime?

Tags: google-project-tango

Playing with the experimental 3D reconstruction, I wanted to adjust the resolution of the meshing at runtime. While I can easily update the value via script, it does not seem to affect the actual meshing in progress. Is there a way to adjust this value or does the Tango service lock in on whatever resolution it has at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution is not mutable after the Tango Service is connected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11720784)

Comment: @VinothKrishnan, this is the correct answer. The resolution is not mutable with current API.

Comment: Just to clarify a little bit more, resolution is not mutable after service is connected. I said runtime in the post, which is a little bit misleading.. Editing it now.. :)